# Converting strings to arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have manipulated a string into the following format:

```
Type___Product___State___Form___Qty____someType___someProduct___someState___someForm___someQty____someOtherType___someOtherProduct...
```

*(3 underscores between values, 4 underscores representing a line break if this was a table)*

What I need to do is Create 5 string arrays (`string[] type`, `string [] product`, ...)
that pull every 5th value string into it.

So example:

```
string[] type = {someType, someOtherType, someOtherOtherType,...}
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a fantastic homework problem to teach you new skills!  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you might want to take a look at the methods in the [`String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String(v=vs.110).aspx) class! More specifically, [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea on how to work with the strings.

```
Private Sub SplitStrings(s As String)
    Dim lines() As String = Split(s, "____")
    For Each line As String In lines
        Dim perLineTokens() As String = line.Split("___")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: For C# yes ... sorry I did it in VB.  I actively flip back and forth between languages

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you need exists in this code example, but you'll need to review it and make modifications for it to fit your exact requirements (hint: % operator would be useful).  Let me know if you have questions.

```
const string test = "Type___Product___State___Form___Qty____someType___someProduct___someState___someForm___someQty____someOtherType___someOtherProduct___someOtherState___someOtherForm___someOtherQty";

var lines = Regex.Split(test, "____");
var strings = new string[lines.Length, 5];
var lineIteration = 0;

foreach (var line in lines)
{
     var values = Regex.Split(line, "___");
     var valueIteration = 0;

     foreach (var value in values)
     {
          strings[lineIteration, valueIteration] = value;
          valueIteration++;
     }

     lineIteration++;
}
```